# How to close a existing PayPal dispute with the API

Tags: paypal

I need to close existing disputes and I would like to do throught API. I searched the [API Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/) but I don't find valuable info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no API's available at PayPal for closing the existing disputes/work with disputes. Login to PayPal account manually and close the disputes. This feature will be available in future, but there is no ETA.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an official link to read about and confirm this?

Comment: We do not have any official URL links with this information. Since this facility is not available for now and the implementation is in pilot mode.

Comment: Thank you! We are interested in being noticed about this feautre, please contact me in PM if you work at PP